.NET on docker-compose.yml can't connect to database
I created a docker-compose.yml file with 3 services, the schoolsystem.api, mongo and postgresql. When I try to access the path http://localhost:8080/swagger I receive a browser message This site can’t be reached and when I try to access a path that it is a route to see all subjects like http://localhost:8080/api/v1/subjects/list I receive the erro below.
I put depends_on to see if it would work, but it didn't.

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.4'

services:
  schoolsystem.api:
    image: schoolsystem.api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SchoolSystem.API/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongodb-container
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
  postgresql:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgresql-container
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=schoolsystem

volumes:
  mongodb-data:
    driver: local 
  pgdata:



Every third question here is about this problem, really, just do the research.
You can't connect to localhost because your database is NOT on localhost. You explicitly set container_name to postgresql-container and therefore you have to set postgresql-container instead of localhost in your settings.

Hi, thank your for your answer, so just let me know, probably I should do something about to create a network between the containers?

The services you specify in your docker-compose.yml file are all attached to the same network by default. You'd need to explicitly specify network configuration only if you have mupltiple compose files.

Right I tried just to see, I created a network networks: school-network: driver: bridge and I put on each service I have with the following command  networks:
- school-network and it didn't work. What do you think it could be?
